# How to Post to Specific Pages?

Tags: posts, pages

I'm working on this WP blog:
http://millerat.com/blog/

I want to post newer articles on the blog's home page and older archived articles from PDFs to the "Articles"page. The "How's your posture?" article is one of  the articles I don't want to show up on the blog's home page, only on the Articles page.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try categories? http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates and http://codex.wordpress.org/Posts_Categories_SubPanel

Comment: I just added that post to the Archive category, but I'm having trouble figuring out the Category Templates. Do you know of any plugins that might be able to do this for me?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Comment: @cmorris1441: the category templates link I posted above is about as simple as it gets. What exactly do you need to figure out?